# two contexts one server jetty

Tags: java, jetty

i have two jetty embedded servers,
localhost:9001/WebApp1 and localhost:9002/WebApp2,
as you can see they're on different ports. 
I'd like them to share the same port during creation of server
is it possible? (BTW they are two separate jar files as well).
so can i do something like this instead
localhost:9001/WebApp1 and localhost:9001/WebApp2

or am I stuck with producing war files then having them 
contained by a tomcat/glassfish server

during creation of server i usually see this

```
ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/WebApp1");
context.setHandler(new WebApp1());
Server server = new Server(9001);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();            
server.join();
```

on second app i'd like to have something that looks like this

```
ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/WebApp2");
context.setHandler(new WebApp2());
Server server = getExistingServer(9001);
server.addHandler(context);
```

i see that there is such method server.getHandlers(); which returns an array of handlers how do i add new handler to the existing list, or get the existing jetty server running at port 9001

Comment: Two separately running applications cannot share a port. However, you can deploy wars in Jetty as well, but that will mean giving up the embedded model.

Comment: it appears the correct way of doing is is with war files no?, if i got it correctly with war i'll be using Servlets instead of Server instances and manually adding handlers is that correct? I'm a java EE noob and preferred jetty because of embedded mode, how ever i'd also like to see my program run online probably with a tomcat/glassfish server

Comment: If you want to target more than just Jetty, using that standard WAR deployment model is the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jetty is a standard servlet container and can of course handle different contexts. 
See section [Embedding Contexts](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html#d0e19153) in Chapter 24 of the Jetty documentation.

Here is the [ManyContexts example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyContexts.java) (part of Jetty docs):

```
public class ManyContexts
{
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
  {
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler("/");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Root Hello"));

    ContextHandler contextFR = new ContextHandler("/fr");
    contextFR.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Bonjoir"));

    ContextHandler contextIT = new ContextHandler("/it");
    contextIT.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Bongiorno"));

    ContextHandler contextV = new ContextHandler("/");
    contextV.setVirtualHosts(new String[] { "127.0.0.2" });
    contextV.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Virtual Hello"));

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context, contextFR, contextIT, contextV });

    server.setHandler(contexts);

    server.start();
    server.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: this sample code works one .jar file but mine has two separate .jar files that i would like to run at tghe same time, when i run the second one i can't use the same port anymore gives me a java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Comment: You have one main class for your application where you start one embedded Jetty. But you can have several contexts. It doesn't matter in which JAR file the correspondig classes are, as far as there are in the classpath. So you have one process running with one Jetty and your two JARs.

Comment: i ended up using .war files, this particular answer does the trick but i'm afraid our server guy will not allow me to run an instance of jetty server because they only want to see tomcat running there, thanks for the answers anyhow